# GIT - Preventing Tagging with uncommited changes

Tags: git

I am trying to see if it is possible to prevent git from taging a revision (or at least pusing it) if there is uncommitted changes?

I am trying to idiot proof our prod relase script.    There is a line in our our production release script that would add a tag in git that represents the current state and the machine we were moving our release to.   However we had a recent incident where somone checked out a vesion from git, made a manual modification to the file in the staging area.  He then  ran our release script which copied the file to our prod systems and then tried to tag it in git.  The problem was that since he made manual modficition the git tagged version didn't match what really got released.

Our normal workflow is 
1)Make changes in local reposotory on our desktops
2)When ready to make a release we create a tag YYYY.MM.DD.VERSION and push with tags to the origin.
3)On the remote unix box we do our releases from we would do the following:
    a)run git checkout on the tag - YYYY.MM.DD.VERSION 
    2)run the release script which would in turn create a second tag that contains both the machine name and version - ie MACHINE_YYYY.MM.DD.VERSION.

The thought was that workflow would allow us to track that the specific version we intended to release matched what was copied to our prod systems.

Today I had someone check-out a release in the staging area and then manual make changes to it before running the release script(I think they copied over it with an older version of the file).  When they ran the release script it made a tag that matched the last commited version not the state of the modified file

If there is uncommited changes I dont want the tagging to happen.. I didnt see an opinion in the git manual though that I could use

Comment: And what if I've spent the entire morning working on new stuff, committing as I go, and suddenly realized I should have added a tag a dozen commits back? Why shouldn't I be able to add a tag without having to commit the mess I currently have in my working directory?

Answer (score 0):

Easy: only do your production releases from a bare for-publication repository, only do your pre-release testing by pulling from that repository, and only tag the release and push the tag back from your pre-release-testing repo.  (edit: and never do anything but testing on your testing repo -- fixes are made in and pushed from development repositories, not test repositories).

Answer (score 0):

This is something that introducing an impersonal CI server like hudson/jenkins would help prevent, to avoid these types of "manual intervention" errors. The CI server would never decide to edit files between git clone & release.

So your (modified) workflow becomes:

1. Make changes in local reposotory on our desktops
2. When ready to make a release we create a tag YYYY.MM.DD.VERSION and push with tags to the origin.
3. The hudson/jenkins CI server (remote unix box; possibly master/slave) has a job configured to do the folowing (possibly triggered by the git push w/ tag):

   - git clone / checkout the tag - YYYY.MM.DD.VERSION
   - run the release script, which creates the second tag containing both the machine name and version - ie MACHINE_YYYY.MM.DD.VERSION